# Single Row Navigation Overflow

Tags: jquery, html, menu, navigation, navigationbar

I have a site  where I have a single row of navigation items. When I reduce the page width items drop onto a second line. Having seen the BBC's very clever solution to this which creates a 'more' dropdown when the page is too narrow to hold all of the list items, I was wondering if anyone has come across a tutorial or plugin for jquery that does the same?

EDIT

Example:`

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reprehenderit, similique.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Est, nobis.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Incidunt, sequi.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nulla, ducimus.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nulla, nobis.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Deserunt, aspernatur?</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Minima, tempore.</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>`
```

When the page starts to get narrow I'm looking for:`

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Reprehenderit, similique.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Est, nobis.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Incidunt, sequi.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nulla, ducimus.</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nulla, nobis.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Deserunt, aspernatur?</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Minima, tempore.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

`
ie. anything wider than the outer ul is moved into a 'More' which can be styled as a dropdown.

Thanks.

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

CSS @media queries, maybe a little Jquery is all you need. Can't give you a working solution without you giving some code samples first.

Comment: I'm wanting to keep things out of the CSS as its for a Wordpress Theme and needs to be relatively flecible, hence not using `@media`.

Comment: Why would you want to keep things out of css?? how else are you planning on doing this?

Comment: Do you know what media queries are? They are pretty flixble, they are actually made to be flexible....

Comment: Yes, I understand Media Queries. Have you had a look at the Beep's site to understand what I'm looking for? I might not be explaining things very well.

Comment: Saying that, I have to apologise - it appears that they have changed things slightly. The site used to dynamically add and remove things from the 'more' dropdown at the top of the page as the site got wider or smaller. It now seems that the main site is fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using responsive design and media queries. To begin, you may be intrested to use some css frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or similars.